# Docker - Feed data from read-only directory on host into container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, large-data-volumes

I'm a relative novice to Docker, so please bear with me if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to give my docker container access to a shared data directory on the host, which has specific group permissions and is read-only for the group of the intended user.

I've already tried `docker run -it -v /data:/data ubuntu /bin/bash` with the resulting error `docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/data': mkdir /data: permission denied`. So it's clearly a permission issue.

The gist I got looking around on google is that if you bind-mount a volume, you need to have read-write permission. 
So I'm looking for an alternative way, possibly with `docker volume`?

The data directory is huge, so any kind of duplication is not feasible. Also, changing permissions is not possible.

System info:

`docker Server Version: 17.03.1-ce`

`Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`

---

**EDIT:**

So I finally figured it out after the helpful comment of @barat.

The problem was, that the exact directory I was trying to mount inside the container had the permissions set up in a way that only members of a specific group could read the contents. I tried everything from `docker run -u userwithaccess`, `docker run --privileged` to adding a user within the `Dockerfile` and specifically assigning the group in question to that user. Nothing worked.

In the end the solution was relatively simple:

The parent directory of my data directory had read access for everyone, i.e. also users which were not members of *the group*. So I was able to mount it without a problem. 
To reach the actual data, I did add the user in the `Dockerfile` to *the group* and made sure it had the same name and `GID`. Finally it was no problem to navigate into the data directory and read any file I wanted.

So I'm not sure if the directory I tried to mount is just a special case, or if it's generally not possible to mount a directory with specific group access.
I found this workaround, but I would still have no solution if the directory I wanted would have been at `/`.

Comment: Have you tried to run it in `privileged` mode?

Comment: yes, unfortunately with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/on/container:ro my/image
```

Default behaviour of bind mounting is rw, but you can switch this to read only (:ro)

Comment: does docker user/group has read access to this path as well? Because IMO doing "docker something" mounts etc are as "docker" user, plus if you have "docker" group created - docker will check if current user is in this group so that you can use docker commands without sudo ... this could mean, that docker group should have at least (?) read access to this path as well ...

Comment: The problem is, I have no influence over permissions, meaning I know the docker group does not have any access to the directory. And with docker user you mean the user calling the docker commands? This one has access, and I was trying to pass this on to the container, without success ...